# Can we create backup job on Oracle PDB instance?

Tags: oracle, database-administration

Can anyone help me on the below?

Is it possible to create backup jobs in oracle pluggable databases or the backup jobs can be created only on the root container database?

Answer (score 0):

RMAN can execute on a PDB as well. You need a user with SYSBACKUP privileges to connect directly to the PDB. See this link for specifics:

https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/multitenant-rman-backup-recovery-cdb-and-pdb-12cr1#:~:text=